# Android MP Chart highlightValue not working, throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mpandroidchart, combinedchart

I'm playing around with Android [MP Chart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) lib to draw awesome charts.

I'm trying to highlight values on my chart, but it **does not puts the highlight to the right place**, or throws **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**.

I've made a little dummy project for it. When user clicks on the next button, **the highlight should move to positive direction.**

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    final int DATA_MAX_COUNT = 30;

    List<MyData> list    = new ArrayList<>(); ///<Dummy data stored in here
    List<Entry>  entries = new ArrayList<>(); ///<Entries for MP Chart

    int highlightIndex = 0; ///<Chart's data index to be highlighted

    CombinedChart combinedChart; ///<I use combined chart because there will be more data sets added later on

    Button prevBtn; ///<Button for highlight control
    Button nextBtn; ///<Button for highlight control

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        combinedChart = (CombinedChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);

        prevBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prev_btn);
        prevBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_btn);
        nextBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        generateData();
        drawChart();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //Clicking buttons should move the highlighted value
        if (v.equals(prevBtn)) {
            if (highlightIndex > 0) {
                highlightIndex--;
            }
        } else if (v.equals(nextBtn)) {
            if (highlightIndex + 1 < DATA_MAX_COUNT) {
                highlightIndex++;
            }
        }

        //Does not work, throws exception
        //combinedChart.highlightValue(new Highlight(highlightIndex, 0, 0));

        //Does not work, throws exception
        //combinedChart.highlightValue(highlightIndex, 0, false);

        //Exception

//        java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-1
//        at com.github.mikephil.charting.data.CombinedData.getDataByIndex(CombinedData.java:152)
//        at com.github.mikephil.charting.data.CombinedData.getEntryForHighlight(CombinedData.java:183)
//        at com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.Chart.highlightValue(Chart.java:635)
//        at com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.Chart.highlightValue(Chart.java:613)


        //Works, but highlights value on chart with like x=0 and y= 190, wtf?
        combinedChart.highlightValue(combinedChart.getHighlighter().getHighlight(highlightIndex, 0));


    }


    //Generating random data to a list
    public void generateData() {
        for (int i = 0; i < DATA_MAX_COUNT; i++) {
            MyData myData = new MyData(new Random().nextInt(100) + 100);
            list.add(myData);
        }
    }

    //Simple func for adding data to entries and drawing chart
    private void drawChart() {

        CombinedData combinedData = new CombinedData();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            MyData myData = list.get(i);
            entries.add(new Entry(i, myData.getValue(), myData));
        }

        LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(entries, "My data list");

        lineDataSet.setHighLightColor(Color.RED);
        lineDataSet.setHighlightLineWidth(3);

        LineData lineData = new LineData();
        lineData.addDataSet(lineDataSet);

        combinedData.setData(lineData);
        combinedChart.setData(combinedData);

        combinedChart.invalidate();
    }


    //Dummy data class
    public static class MyData {

        private int value;

        public MyData(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't get it why I'm getting

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-1

Because what the hell is **-1**? and what is **10**? There are n**ot a single thing in my code which is 10**, and why does any of the **chart's functions getting -1?**

I'm using

> com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3

Please help if you can.

**E D I T:**

I've added  `combinedChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);` to the chart.

With this callback `onValueSelected(Entry, Highlight)` I can test this thing in another way. It gives a Highlight object. If I does nothing in this callback, the chart draws the highlights well. If I call it programatically with the same X value, it throws the usual exception or draws the highlight to wrong position. (to zero)

See the callback:

```
 @Override
    public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {
        float x = h.getX();

        Log.i("Highlighted", "Actual highlight: " + x);

        //Getting the same exception as above
        //combinedChart.highlightValue(x, 0, false);

        //Does not works, draws to x=0 position with any given x
        combinedChart.highlightValue(combinedChart.getHighlighter().getHighlight(x, 0));
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is solution:

```
Highlight high = new Highlight(highlightIndex, 0, 0);
high.setDataIndex(0);
combinedChart.highlightValue(high, false);
```

You need to add `high.setDataIndex(0);` line.

**Explaination**:

In `Highlight` constructor first parameter is X value, the value you increase or decrease. Second is index of graph you want to select. Since you have only one, you specify 0 there. Also you should specify it second time `high.setDataIndex(0);` (otherwise it is treated as -1, bug ! ) and your code will work:

[image]